# Understanding sorting algorithm from "Computer Science Distilled" book

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**What do I have:** algorithm in pseudocode from the "Computer Science Distilled" book (p. 27)

```
function selection_sort(list)
    for current <- 1 ... list.length - 1
        smallest <- current
        for i <- current + 1 ... list.length
            if list[i] < list[smallest]
                smallest <- i
        list.swap_items(current, smallest)
```

I'm trying to understand it, so I wrote it in Go:

```golang
func main() {
    list := []int{5, 2, 7, 9}
    for current := 1; current < len(list)-1; current++ {
        smallest := current
        for i := current + 1; i < len(list); i++ {
            if list[i] < list[smallest] {
                smallest = i
            }
        }
        current_tmp := list[current]
        smallest_tmp := list[smallest]
        list[current], list[smallest] = smallest_tmp, current_tmp
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", list)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Rg-hSiscfV6)

And output is `[5 2 7 9]`.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Go, but googling confirms that Go has zero based numbering.
In your example you start from `1` (should be `0`).

Another thing -- why do you need `current_tmp` and `smallest_tmp`?

So I suggest the following:

```
func main() {
    list := []int{5, 2, 7, 9}
    for current := 0; current < len(list)-1; current++ {
        smallest := current
        for i := current + 1; i < len(list); i++ {
            if list[i] < list[smallest] {
                smallest = i
            }
        }
        list[current], list[smallest] = list[smallest], list[current]
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", list)
}
```